# How to return all rows in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to do a trivial SQL query with CodeIgniter, such as `"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TRUE"`

maybe one way could be this :

```
$this->db->get_where('mytable' , array('42' => '42'));
```

but "42"="42" seems unnecessary to me. How can I initialize the array so that it (CI) does not do any unnecessary computations ?

Comment: Edit, right after asking, I remembered I can use db->get :) anyway, it will be easy points for someone. and maybe a help for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get all rows without any condition, then you can use

```
$this->db->get("mytable");
```

There is no need of `get_where` because your query `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TRUE` will always return all records.